# Remove facebook contact from call option in Lumia 820!

Tags: contacts, facebook, windows-8, accounts

I am using windows phone 8.1
I have added facebook account, so it is now showing fb account in people section but here using filter option I excluded fb accounts which doesn't have phone number in my contact list and it is now showing fb details(photos,post etc) for those are in my contact list.
 But my problem is same not happening when I go from Call Option of phone, It shows all fb account in contact list. 
So how do I hide them in call option?